# While binding combobox how could I get binded data in uppercase format in c#.net

Tags: c#, desktop-application, uppercase

I want to bind the combobox in c#.net windows application and that also the binded combobox I want in uppercase word.

Now, I bind the combobox successfully but the problem is that I didnt get any uppercase word in it.

Here is my code,

```
public void BindDropdownList(ComboBox f_dropdown, string tblname, string display_field, string value_fldName, string wherecondition = "")
{
    try
    {
        string qrysel = "select " + value_fldName + "," + display_field + " from " + tblname + " " + wherecondition + "";
        DataTable dt_list_detail = new DataTable();

        dt_list_detail = clsObjDataAccess.GetDataTable(qrysel);

        if (dt_list_detail != null)
        {
            if (dt_list_detail.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                f_dropdown.DataSource = dt_list_detail;
                f_dropdown.DisplayMember = display_field;
                f_dropdown.ValueMember = value_fldName;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

I tried many things but didnt work like

```
f_dropdown.DataSource = dt_list_detail;
f_dropdown.DisplayMember = display_field.ToUpper();
f_dropdown.ValueMember = value_fldName.ToUpper();
```

next

```
f_dropdown.DisplayMember = display_field.ToString().ToUpperInvariant();
```

and many other thing also but the same thing happing with me that is not working in upper case word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112169/how-to-convert-an-input-string-to-uppercase-in-c-sharp

Comment: use `toUpper()` method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @panohh. Sorry brother the url which you suggest that I tried but that solution is not working for me.

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer I tried but not getting the solution.

Comment: Also you should not be concatenating strings to build a sql query, that puts you at risk for sql injection

Comment: @panohh can you show me by the syntax or by I applied code?

Comment: So you want to insert small letters into the `combobox` and this letters should be uppercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following.

```
f_dropdown.Format += (s, arg) =>
{
  arg.Value = arg.Value.ToString().ToUpperInvariant();
};
```

Test Collection

```
_persons = new List<Person>
 {
    new Person(){Id=1, Name = "Anu"},
    new Person(){Id=1, Name = "Jia"},
 };



f_dropdown.DataSource = 
f_dropdown.DisplayMember = "Name";
f_dropdown.Format += (s, arg) =>
{
  arg.Value = arg.Value.ToString().ToUpperInvariant();
};
```

Output

[image]

Comment: @karan I have updated the Answer with complete code and screenshot, could you verify it with your code. May be post your attempted code as well ?

Comment: Awsome brother. Thanks a lot. for save my night. :)